# Resolving "Dictionary does not contain key" error applying function to feature collection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, fields-attributes, features, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, function

I am adding two properties to each feature in a feature collection based on two images within each feature, currently represented as properties themselves. I got this feature collection through performing an inner join on two image collections. To add them, I am running this function:

```
var innerJoined = innerJoin.apply(perpSum, finalSent2, filterTimeEq);

var test = innerJoined.map(function(feature) {                                                             
  var percObs = ee.Image(feature.get('primary')).reduceRegion(                                             
      {geometry: studyArea.geometry(), reducer: ee.Reducer.median(), scale: 30}).get('precipitation');     
  var NDTIObs = ee.Image(feature.get('secondary')).reduceRegion(                                           
      {geometry: nilo, reducer: ee.Reducer.median(), scale: 30}).get('NDTI');                              
  return feature.set('precipitation', percObs).set('NDTI', NDTIObs.get('NDTI'));                           
}); 
print('test2', test2);
```

However, when I run the code, I get this error:

```
FeatureCollection (Error)
Error in map(ID=74_74): Dictionary.get: Dictionary does not contain key: precipitation
```

When I've been debugging, I've found that if I just take 1 feature and apply a similar version of the code that is in the function, I don't get the error, and the value I want gets added to the feature properties:

```
var feat = innerJoined.first();

var percObs = ee.Image(feat.get('primary')).reduceRegion(                                             
      {geometry: studyArea.geometry(), reducer: ee.Reducer.median(), scale: 30}).get('precipitation');
var test1 = feat.set('precipitation', percObs);
print('test1', test1);
```

Because I can get around this issue if I do not use the function, I think it is the function that is causing the problem. However, I haven't found a precedent for this problem yet, or anything in the documentation that I have found helpful.

Is the function the problem, or I am I doing something in the single addition of the property that I am not doing in the function?

If you want to see the full code that is commented out, you can do so here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/8e2656ba08560e002e422b1a05aaa555
To see the issue area please scroll to the bottom with the area marked "Focus area"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary image in the last feature in your join (with system:index = "74:74"), has no bands.  So the reduceRegion returns nothing.  That image corresponds to 2031-03, for which data doesn't exist in the CHIRPS dataset yet.

You can simply filter that image out of the perpSum result before joining with it.